# json parse error when sending array of entity in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2

when sending json data to my service i get this error

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.eksamen_backend.model.Sub_assembly` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)]

i only get it with one of my objects, which to me looks identical to my other objects.

this is the entity that doesnt work

```
package com.example.eksamen_backend.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "sub_assembly")
public class Sub_assembly {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sub_assembly_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sub_assembly_generator", sequenceName = "sub_assembly_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "sub_assembly_id")
    private Long sub_assembly_id = 0L;
    @Column(name = "sub_assembly_name")
    private String sub_assembly_name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("sub_assemblies")
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Sub_assembly_part",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub_assembly_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "part_id")
    )
    private List<Part> parts= new ArrayList<>();

    public void setPart(Part part) {
        this.parts.add(part);
    }
    public List<Part> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }
    public Sub_assembly(String name) {
        this.sub_assembly_name = name;
    }
}
```

this is the entity that contains the entity that doesnt work

```
package com.example.eksamen_backend.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "machine_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "machine_sequence", sequenceName = "machine_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "machine_id")
    private Long machine_id = 0L;
    @Column(name = "machine_name")
    private String machine_name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "machine_Sub_assembly",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub_assembly_id")
    )
    private List<Sub_assembly> sub_assemblies= new ArrayList<>();

    public void setSub_assemblies(Sub_assembly sub_assemblies) {
        this.sub_assemblies.add(sub_assemblies);
    }
    public List<Sub_assembly> getSub_assemblies() {
        return sub_assemblies;
    }

    public Machine(String name ) {
        this.machine_name = name;
    }
}
```

the json text i am trying to send is this

```
{
  "customer_id" : 0,
  "name" : "mockTestCustomer",
  "orders" : [ {
    "orderId" : 0,
    "machines" : [ {
      "machine_id" : 0,
      "machine_name" : "mockTestMachine",
      "sub_assemblies" :  [{
        "sub_assembly_id" : 0,
        "sub_assembly_name" : "mockTestSubAssembly",
        "parts" : [ {
          "part_id" : 0,
          "part_name" : "mockTestPart"
        },
        {
          "part_id" : 0,
          "part_name" : "mockTestPart2"
        } ]
      }] 
    } ]
  } ],
  "addresses" : [ {
    "address_id" : 0,
    "address" : "mockTestAddress"
  } ],
  "customerId" : 0,
  "customerName" : "mockTestCustomer"
}
```

i have tried sending the json without the [] around sub_assembly and then it works but  i cant have more than one sub assembly attached which is needed. Part also works fine which i would assumed would have the same problem but it doesnt